# Array resize performance, setting length property vs. repeated pushing

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, v8

So I was benchmarking the following code, trying to figure out which would be more performant:

```
'use strict';

function addSetToArrayA(array, set) {
  for (const v of set) {
    array.push(v);
  }
}
function addSetToArrayB(array, set) {
  const origLength = array.length;
  const newLength = array.length + set.size;
  array.length = newLength;
  array[newLength - 1] = 0;
  let i = origLength;
  for (const v of set) {
    array[i++] = v;
  }
}

const set = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);

console.time('addSetToArrayA');
for (let i = 0;i<0xffffff;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  addSetToArrayA(base, set);
}
console.timeEnd('addSetToArrayA');

console.time('addSetToArrayB');
for (let i = 0;i<0xffffff;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  addSetToArrayB(base, set);
}
console.timeEnd('addSetToArrayB');
```

The result surprised me a little:

```
addSetToArrayA: 728.773ms
addSetToArrayB: 3296.437ms
```

So I did another benchmark:

```
'use strict';

const iters = 0xfffff;

console.time('32 push');
for (let i = 0;i<iters;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  for (let k = 0;k<32;++k) {
    base.push(undefined);
  }
}
console.timeEnd('32 push');

console.time('32 length');
for (let i = 0;i<iters;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  base.length = 32;
}
console.timeEnd('32 length');

console.time('64 push');
for (let i = 0;i<iters;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  for (let k = 0;k<64;++k) {
    base.push(undefined);
  }
}
console.timeEnd('64 push');

console.time('64 length');
for (let i = 0;i<iters;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  base.length = 64;
}
console.timeEnd('64 length');

console.time('128 push');
for (let i = 0;i<iters;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  for (let k = 0;k<128;++k) {
    base.push(undefined);
  }
}
console.timeEnd('128 push');

console.time('128 length');
for (let i = 0;i<iters;++i) {
  const base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  base.length = 128;
}
console.timeEnd('128 length');
```

The results were in line with what I experienced previously:

```
32 push: 132.061ms
32 length: 180.745ms
64 push: 284.575ms
64 length: 212.465ms
128 push: 586.747ms
128 length: 268.689ms
```

Eg. for relatively small arrays re-sizing via `.length` is slower than repeatedly using `.push()`, while for larger arrays it's faster (as expected).

Is V8 performing different types of array resizing when using `.length = ...` vs. `.push(...)`?
Is this related to how V8 handles sparse arrays?

Running on Node@10.12 with similar results in chrome.

Comment: Notice that calling `push` N times on an array of initially X elements has a different result from setting the array's length to N.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

V8 developer here. The short answer is that `.push()` is super optimized, whereas writing to `.length` is a fairly slow operation (partially because of what the JavaScript spec says it must do, and partially because we haven't optimized it quite as much -- but even if we did, it wouldn't become as fast as `.push()` for a few elements).

In fact, you'll notice a similar difference between writing to `.length` to shorten an array and calling `.pop()` a couple of times.

Personally I think this is not a bad state to be in: your `.push` based code is concise, intuitive, and readable. The `.length` based alternative looks like an attempt to squeeze out a bit of extra performance at the cost of making the code uglier and more complicated -- isn't it nice that that does *not* help? Write the code you want to write, let the engine worry about making it fast! :-)

> Is V8 performing different types of array resizing when using .length = ... vs. .push(...)?

Writing to `.length` and calling `.push(...)` are very different operations (the latter is pretty straightforward, the former must perform a bunch of checks), so yeah, what V8 does under the hood is necessarily different. The resizing itself, if/once it happens, is the same.

> Is this related to how V8 handles sparse arrays?

Not in your example. In general, writing to `.length` must check whether the array should transition to sparse mode, but that check itself is pretty fast.

Comment: Wait, you say that `while (arr.length > n) arr.pop()` is faster than `arr.length = n`?

Comment: Thanks for answering those questions, would you mind going a little bit more into details what checks are performed when writing to `.length` vs. `.push`? Linking to the individual specs would be fine too :)

Comment: Doesn't `array[newLength - 1] = 0;` in the `addSetToArrayB` cause it to become a sparse array?

Comment: @SimonSchick The spec doesn't dictate which checks an implementation actually needs to perform

Comment: @Bergi: you can call `arr.pop()` several times for the cost of one `arr.length = n` call. I'm not sure where the threshold is, probably a few dozen? -- Define "sparse array". It'll become "holey" (which really is a tiny internal implementation detail, nothing to worry about), but not necessarily "dictionary mode", depending on the value of `newLength` and current engine heuristics. -- @SimonSchick: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-arraysetlength and https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.push

Comment: @jmrk Yeah, "holey" is what I meant, IIRC it is still to be avoided as it cannot be converted back to a dense(?) array.

Comment: @Bergi: IMHO the concept of "holey" arrays has gotten undue attention recently. The impact really is minor; in the vast majority of cases (aside from microbenchmarks where every single machine instruction matters) you won't be able to measure the difference. Almost all code has way more important things to worry about (for performance, correctness, maintainability, and readability) than whether or not the engine internally even distinguishes between "holey" and "packed" arrays.

Comment: @jmrk I believe I remember them from [this talk](https://youtu.be/EhpmNyR2Za0) which warns to avoid them, but maybe things changed since then.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I believe that talk caused much of the "undue attention" I mentioned. Nothing has changed since then -- but the difference is usually too small to matter, and the talk probably didn't make that clear enough. It's more of a "fun fact: V8 even goes as far as saving a few machine instructions by doing ..." kind of thing. "dictionary" vs "flat" storage matters (depending on situation you really want the one or the other), "packed" vs "holey" usually does not matter.

Comment: I check it out: 1 pop is taken 1.5ns, set .length to zero - 100ns, so 80 pop's is equal 1 length setting