Why is pre-allocation of arrays slower than dynamic pushing in JavaScript?
I have been testing two methods of array creation and initialization in JavaScript using Node.js. One method involves dynamically pushing elements into the array, while the other method involves pre-allocating the array to a specific size and then setting each element. Surprisingly, the pre-allocated array method performed significantly worse, and I'm unsure why this is the case.
Here is the code I used for testing:
function testPush(size) {
  let start = process.hrtime.bigint();
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  let end = process.hrtime.bigint();
  return Number(end - start) / 1e6; // Convert to milliseconds
}

function testPreAllocated(size) {
  let start = process.hrtime.bigint();
  let array = new Array(size);
  //   let array = new Uint32Array(size);
  //   let array = Array.from({ length: size });
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = i;
  }
  let end = process.hrtime.bigint();
  return Number(end - start) / 1e6; // Convert to milliseconds
}

function compareArrays() {
  const size = 1e8; // 100 million
  console.log(`Testing with array size: ${size}`);

  console.log("Starting push test...");
  let pushTime = testPush(size);
  console.log(`Push test completed in ${pushTime.toFixed(2)} ms`);

  console.log("Starting pre-allocated test...");
  let preAllocatedTime = testPreAllocated(size);
  console.log(`Pre-allocated test completed in ${preAllocatedTime.toFixed(2)} ms`);
}

compareArrays();

Output:
Testing with array size: 100000000
Starting push test...
Push test completed in 1624.93 ms
Starting pre-allocated test...
Pre-allocated test completed in 4824.86 ms

I am using Node.js version 20.12.2. My expectation was that pre-allocating the array would be faster because the JavaScript engine wouldn't need to resize the array continually. However, the results show the opposite. Why does pre-allocating an array result in worse performance compared to dynamically pushing elements into an array in this case?

Interestingly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481918/how-does-v8-optimise-the-creation-of-very-large-arrays asks the exact opposite question, about why the pre-allocating version is faster! (But that was from five years ago -- I could well imagine that newer optimizations might have changed the picture.)

Similar results in the browser, pre-allocation is about 30% slower

I did some experiments and found something about the size 50331648 and 50331649. For some reason pre-allocation time for size 50331648 is about 2300 ms and sizes greater than it the time goes to 3400 ms. As the ratio is about 3/2, probably has something to do with array resizing.

put it down to optimizations :p - test with 1e7 and prealloc is 3 times faster than push

It seems that there are specific sizes where pushing outperforms pre-allocation, possibly due to internal optimizations in how arrays handle memory.

I'm no V8 internals expert, but I would be a little surprised if new Array(whatever) really allocated a bunch of contiguous memory for the array, at least above some fairly large number. Like, new Array(12), well sure what's it going to hurt.  But new Array(bigNumber) would be kind-of crazy to "believe" for the runtime. Maybe it could "learn" after some iterations, but given the wild stuff V8 does internally for object access optimization, I think the answer is somewhere in there.

@Pointy: feel free to be surprised that up to N = 32 million, new Array(N) will actually preallocate what you requested :-)

@jmrk well that's a bigger number than I would have guessed, but it's basically what I was getting at.

When you do new Array(size) with size being more 32 million (the constant kMaxFastArrayLength in V8 to be precise), V8 creates a dictionary-like object rather than a "real" array. The behavior is the same as far as users are concerned (ie, you can still call push, pop, map, iter, access elements with [], etc), but performance is much worse (but memory usage is much better if you end up not populating the whole array).
This doesn't happen when repeatedly calling array.push: the underlying V8 object remains a proper array.
You can confirm this by setting size to 32 * 1024 * 1024 and then 32 * 1024 * 1024 + 1: the performance of testPreAllocated drop from 151ms to 987ms (on my machine).
You can also confirm this by running something like this in v8 on the command line (run with --allow-natives-syntax):
let fast_arr = new Array(32 * 1024 * 1024);
%DebugPrint(fast_arr);

let slow_arr = new Array(32 * 1024 * 1024 + 1);
%DebugPrint(slow_arr);

The 1st one prints map: 0x1b6e0018cc81 <Map[16](HOLEY_SMI_ELEMENTS)> (which means that the array is indeed represented internally as a proper array), while the second one prints map: 0x1b6e00198701 <Map[16](DICTIONARY_ELEMENTS)> (which means that the array is represented internally as a dictionary).

Yes, you are right, with 100m items the pre-allocation is slower. My guess that due this size the assignment by an index gets slower or other reasons.
Nonetheless, 10m size is faster, so in general the pre-allocation is faster. And it really pre-allocates heap memory, more details in my post here.
` Chrome/125
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                        n=10000      |    n=100000     |    n=10000000    |   n=100000000  
non pre-allocated     2.99x  x10k 248 |   3.59x x1k 607 |   4.68x x10 1066 | ■ 1.00x x1  986
pre-allocated       ■ 1.00x x100k 830 | ■ 1.00x x1k 169 | ■ 1.00x x10  228 |   2.69x x1 2651
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


let $length = 10;
const $chunks = [1000, 10000, 1000000, 10000000];
const arr = Array.from({length: $length}, (_, i) => i);

// @benchmark non pre-allocated
{
  const result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result.push(arr[i]);
  }
  result;
}

// @benchmark pre-allocated
{
  const result = Array(arr.length);
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result[i] = arr[i];
  }
  result;
}
/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



